# How to correctly enable/test VA-API on Intel Sandy Bridge?

Tags: intel-graphics, vaapi

I would like to know which package I have to install and how to test that is working fine?

I know there are many question similar but no one is complete and clear to me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`libva-intel-vaapi-driver`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libva-intel-vaapi-driver) [image: Install libva-intel-vaapi-driver] [`vainfo`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vainfo) [image: Install vainfo]

Then run `vainfo` to check if you see the entry points for some profiles:

```
[...]
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
    VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
    [...]
```

For all GStreamer-based video players, this package should be sufficient: [`gstreamer0.10-vaapi`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gstreamer0.10-vaapi) [image: Install gstreamer0.10-vaapi]. If I'm correct most standard video players like Totem are GStreamer based.

VLC is a different story, but it's being built with the `--enable-libva` build flag in Ubuntu (as shown by the `apt-get source vlc`). This means it *should* just work by enabling it in the configuration:

[image]

Or, manually, on the command line:

```
vlc --ffmpeg-hw -v
[...]
libva: VA-API version 0.32.0
[0x7feeecc02a28] avcodec decoder: Using VA API version 0.32 for hardware decoding.
```

Comment: By the way I'm having tearing with VLC is it the same for you ?

Comment: @Postadelmaga Tearing should belong in another question. Lots of similar already exist: [Tearing intel HD 3000 with Ubuntu 11.10 (AMD 64)](http://askubuntu.com/q/77552/88802), [Desktop tearing kubuntu 12.04 with Intel HD](http://askubuntu.com/q/235561/88802). I have an Nvidia card (unfortunately), so I can't test it for you.

Comment: `Warning: option --ffmpeg-hw no longer exists`

Answer (score 3):

1. Decoding:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install i965-va-driver libva-intel-vaapi- driver vainfo
   ```

   Then setup vlc to use hardware decoding, run it from the command line (to get the debug messsages) and open am .mp4 file. You should see:

   ```
   [0x1781058] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
   libva info: VA-API version 0.35.0
   libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
   libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
   libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_35
   libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
   [0x7fd825a569a8] avcodec decoder: Using VA API version 0.35 for **hardware decoding**.*
   ```
2. Encoding: Install Gstreamer, libgstremaer-vaapi1.x, i965-va-driver;
   The following command will launch a gstremaer filter graph which takes input from your web camera (/dev/video0) then encodes and muxes into **test2.mp4** file:

   ```
   gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 num-buffers=1800 ! video/x-raw,format= I420,width=640,height=480 ! vaapipostproc ! queue ! vaapiencode_h264 ! qtmux ! filesink location=test2.mp4
   ```

   It will **fail** if you don't have hardware encoding support for your sandy bridge graphics (HD 2000/3000 GPU).
   Note it fails for me (Core i7, HD3000 graphics) and according Intel it shouldn't, because HD2000/3000 supports H.264 HW encoding....

Comment: Shouldn't `libva-intel-vaapi- driver` be: `libva-intel-vaapi-driver`

Answer (score 2):

Just a quicknote on Totem : it's not possible to use the gstreamer-vaapi right now for Totem as it use a special GTK widget which does not interface with gstreamer like a classic player. the team is working on it.

Comment: Just to add that progress on that work can be followed at bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/997370

Answer (score -1):

Just install vainfo and you are all set.
To install that open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get install vainfo
```

Comment: I believe the `vainfo` package does not install any driver-specific va-api libraries.