# Why is the monitor's backlight turning off, when I use the Intel® Sandybridge Mobile drivers?

Tags: 13.04, drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, intel

Recently, I have installed Ubuntu on my Acer Aspire Notebook. Everything works flawlessly, except for the graphics card. For example when I try to watch movies they run at a much lower frame rate than in Windows. I suspect the system is running in VGA mode.

Therefore I checked the boot options with cat /proc/cmdline, and it seems nomodeset is activated. However, if I try to remove that, the Display turns off.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? If you're running 13.04 as tagged, then your Intel graphics card should work perfectly fine without any additional driver! How exactly are you watching the movies? What application are you using, what codecs do these movies have? Etc.

Comment: Usually I am using VLC but I have also tried totem. One of the films I tried is encoded with H.264/MPEG-4, another one with MPEG-1/2 Video. The first film, is recognised, but runs with a low frame rate. The second one, however, does not work at all.

Comment: Please verify your VA-API settings. See http://askubuntu.com/a/247922/88802

Comment: @gertvdijk I tried it, but it seems not to work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "seems not to work"? Does VA-API not work or does it, but doesn't it solve your primary issue? Please be more specific and **edit** your question to include this information instead of posting comments. That is how this Q&A site works. It's not a discussion forum, you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found the problem, and solved it. The problem was apparently that the monitor backlight was completely switched off. Until now I have used the Bootoption nomodeset to prevent it. However, I just had to add the following boot options instead:

```
acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux video.use_bios_initial_backlight=0
```