# ASUS X53S Intel Graphics and Unity 3D

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus

I just bought a ASUS X53S. Everything works flawlessly except that I can't run Unity 3D on it because NVIDIA Linux drivers currently doesn't support Optimus. So I'm stuck with the other integrated Intel Graphics Adapter. I'm already installed BumbleBee but it doesn't help with Unity 3D thing. Will the Xorg driver ever support OpenGL and especially `GLX_texture_from_pixmap` so that Unity 3D will work with it? The Intel driver is really snappy with Unity 2D and seems to support most other X acceleration features such as smooth scrolling.

Comment: Lets hope it will, but you had better ask someone directly involved in its development.

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded upgrades when you are installing ubuntu 12.04 it happens. Do not download upgrades when installing it. After install you can freely download upgrades and restricted extras.

Answer (score 0):

You [cannot use the nvidia card on an Optimus system](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969). When you've installed nvidia before Bumblebee, you need to restart the X server by rebooting for example.

If after rebooting you still experience "lag", consider [Screen tearing in 11.10 with intel graphics](https://askubuntu.com/q/73909/6969). A user (Dragon707) in the #bumblebee IRC channel owns an ASUS K53SC and reported that this makes Unity more usable.