# Screen tearing in Fluxbox

Tags: visual-artifacts, tearing, fluxbox

I using fluxbox as my window manager and I'm experiencing tearing when viewing videos.  Tearing does not happen under Gnome or Unity.  I primarily use VLC to play videos in full-screen (1920x1080).  Tearing happens regardless of the player I use, as long as I'm in fluxbox and full-screen.

I have an Intel on-board video card.

I've tried following the instructions at [Screen tearing in 11.10 with intel graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73909/screen-tearing-in-11-10-with-intel-graphics) but it has no effect.

My questions are:

- What is different about how fluxbox handles tearing?  It seems like compiz isn't having any effect -- what setting should I tweak?
- What can I do to reduce/remove tearing when viewing videos under fluxbox?

Answer (score 1):

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_Graphics#Tear-free_video

Try this. Also, If you are using Chrome disable the pepperflashplugin and use the official flashplayer instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I don't have an /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf file (I've got /etc/X11, but that's it) -- where should I put the tear-free option?