# Screen tearing in video playback - Ubuntu 14.10 - Unity - Intel Ivy Bridge

Tags: graphics, video, intel, tearing

I am experiencing severe screen tearing while playing full screen video.

Ivy Bridge graphics - Ubuntu 14.10 x64 (Unity).

Existing answers such as [Screen tearing in 11.10 with intel graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73909/screen-tearing-in-11.10-with-intel-graphics/75906#75906) do not appear to fix the problem.

I had this problem on Ubuntu GNOME and was able to fix it by running `echo CLUTTER_PAINT=disable-clipped-redraws:disable-culling >> /etc/environment` but this solution does not apply to Unity apparently.